# Emacs - No line numbering for empty lines

Tags: emacs, line-numbers

I'm trying to setup line numbering in Emacs.
Linum works well, but when I open two buffers, numbering for empty lines disappears.
I use Manjaro Linux. Emacs works in the terminal.

[Here's screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3yy1.png)

Code from .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda () (linum-mode 1)))

(unless window-system
  (add-hook 'linum-before-numbering-hook
    (lambda ()
      (setq-local linum-format-fmt
          (let ((w (length (number-to-string
                (count-lines (point-min) (point-max))))))
            (concat "%"(number-to-string w) "d"))))))

(defun linum-format-func (line)
  (concat
   (propertize (format linum-format-fmt line) 'face 'linum)
   (propertize " " 'face 'mode-line)))

(unless window-system
  (setq linum-format 'linum-format-func))
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25082664/2112489 and http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/4179/2287  Perhaps one of them applies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You might be able to fix this by replacing *all* of the above code with just

   ```
   (global-linum-mode 1)
   ```
2. linum-mode should already do the variable-size-format thing for
   you. Don't know why you're reinventing the wheel.
3. Maybe your problem is that you're trying to string `concat` two `propertize`-d objects. You can avoid this by making your formatting like `"%3d "` instead of `"%3d"` and concatting `" "` later:

   ```
   (add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda () (linum-mode 1)))

   (unless window-system
     (add-hook 'linum-before-numbering-hook
       (lambda ()
         (setq-local linum-format-fmt
             (let ((w (length (number-to-string
                   (count-lines (point-min) (point-max))))))
               (concat "%" (number-to-string w) "d "))))))

   (defun linum-format-func (line)
     (propertize (format linum-format-fmt line) 'face 'linum))

   (unless window-system
     (setq linum-format 'linum-format-func))
   ```